# Excel Coulmn datas multiply with constant Number & Result should be natural number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Suppose I have a column A and datas like below

```
  A 
23454
21215
12454
45454
```

& Want to multiply the whole column datas with 0.001 
Example: 23454*0.001 = 23.454
Wanted Result 23 only not 23.454

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **B1** enter:

```
=INT(A1*0.001)
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

To change the values **in place**, try this VBA macro:

```
Sub FixKolumnA()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 4
        Cells(i, 1).Value = Int(Cells(i, 1).Value * 0.001)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the round() function, or the roundup() or rounddown() depending on what you need.

For the example you give then rounddown() would work:

```
=rounddown(A1*0.001,0)
```

assuming the number is in cell A1.

Roundup() will give the result 24 from 23200...